# how to move an image in bootstrap 4 card header to the right?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap for my website and i try to make a text to the left side of the header and an image to the right side. I've tried to use a row container and use justify-content-end but it is not in the same height as the header. I would like to have them on the same height.

This what i tried:

```
<div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
  <div class="card-header">
  <h4 class="card-title Anton"><?php echo($thread['title']); ?>
    <span class="row justify-content-end">
        <img height="32" width="32" src="assets/img/edit.png" href="/test" style="padding: none; margin: none;">
    </span>
  </h4>

<hr />
...
```

But it just looks like this:[The Image is more on the bottom then the header!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7wYR.jpg)

Comment: May I ask what is justify-content-end? If you're using FlexBox shouldn't it be flex-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated a simple case of what you have described. I used Flex Box to create what you have asked. I created a container div, then two child divs (left div and right div) then assigned flex: 1 do both the left and right div to give them an equal width. After that I assigned the image (in the right div) `justify-content: flex-end` This moves the content of the right div to the far right of the div.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title">
    <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="smiley.gif">
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  display: flex;

  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: red;
}

.title {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.img {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is a quick reference for you to use:

```
justify-content: flex-start means content will start from the left
justify-content: center means content will be centered in the middle
justify-content: flex-end means content will be pushed to the end of the div (right)
```

I have put together a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/k5uj04dt/6/